# How to store a big built in data in a iOS App

Tags: ios, xcode

I’m trying to create an iPad app with information about architecture (buildings, cities, architects,…) but I don’t want to use internet connection. I would like to include all the data when building it so the user automatically gets everything when he downloads the app.

The user won’t be able to modify this data. The preferences will be stored separately. I have though that more data about, for example, other cities could be added with updates.

How should I do this?

Should I use Core Data?

I would like the data to be localizable and support at least two languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data has some structure to it (consistent fields, which seems likely) then CoreData can be a very good choice. You can put a .sqlite file in your application bundle as a resource, and have localized versions of it. Keep in mind though that any time your data changes you will have to push an app update, unless you write some code to extract the resource to the local storage, and to download new versions and update the data when necessary.

Comment: I'm aware about the need of an update. I'm not worried about it. With future versions I could make it smarter and capable of downloading just the new data from a server, but for now is OK.

Comment: The combination of SQL and CoreData is what I need. Thank you.